# Duplicate block on checkout cart page

Tags: magento-enterprise, checkout, onestepcheckout

I'm attempting to create custom checkout with the checkout on the cart page and running into an issue where the cart is being duplicated at the bottom of the page. Here is the code:

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
    <update handle="kom_checkout_onepage" />

    <label>Shopping Cart</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/cart-checkout-wrapper.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/kom_checkout.js</name></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
            <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
            <action method="chooseTemplate"/>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.top_methods" as="top_methods" translate="label">
                <label>Payment Methods Before Checkout Button</label>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.cart.form.before" as="form_before" translate="label">
                <label>Shopping Cart Form Before</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" translate="label">
                <label>Payment Methods After Checkout Button</label>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/multishipping_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.multishipping" template="checkout/multishipping/link.phtml"/>
            </block>

            <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>
            <block type="checkout/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>

            <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.cart.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/cart/totals.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>

</checkout_cart_index>
```

If I remove the block `<reference name="content">...</reference>` then there is only one cart being shown at the top where I want it. The issue is, that it's not in my layout file now, it's actually being created from the base checkout.xml file. What am I missing?

What I am trying to accomplish is only having one cart show up.

Comment: If I do understand correctly the core XML file already creates the cart and then there is your XML file adding the same blocks again. Why are you adding the XML again, what are you trying to accomplish? What is the name of your XML file and what is the layout handle kom_checkout_onepage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, see my comment to your question.

Fact is that if your cart is displayed twice you (or some extension) defined the `checkout/cart` block (and its children) a second time in the layout files.

If the layout XML is duplicated to modify one of the already defined block then reference it in your XML, e.g.

```
<!-- modify the template -->
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="checkout/cart_shipping">
        <action method="setTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/shipping.phtml</value></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

If you want to move the cart, use `unsetChild` and `insert`, e.g.:

```
<!-- move the cart -->
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <alias>checkout.cart</alias>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="insert">
            <block>checkout.cart</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
<checkout_cart_index>
```

If my answer doesn't help you please clarify by answering the questions in my comment and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.